# MySQL Get most replyed threads in X days join threads take about 1 second

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, vbulletin, sqlperformance

I want to display the 10 threads of a vbulletin based forum which had most replys this week. So I wrote a query to count all the posts in a timespan grouped by the threadid to make sure that every thread is only once in this list:

```
SELECT post.postid, COUNT(post.postid) AS replys
FROM post
WHERE post.visible = 1
AND post.dateline > DATE_SUB("2016-01-21", INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
GROUP BY post.threadid
ORDER BY replys DESC, post.dateline DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query took about 0.3 seconds on a database where *posts* have about 400.000 rows and *threads* about 40.000 rows, which seems a bit long, but is still acceptable - also because it can be cached.

But I also need some information of the *thread* table like the titel, which requires a JOIN:

```
SELECT post.postid, COUNT(post.postid) AS replys,
thread.title, thread.views, thread.replycount 
FROM post
INNER JOIN thread ON(thread.threadid = post.threadid)
WHERE post.visible = 1
AND post.dateline > DATE_SUB("2016-01-21", INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
GROUP BY post.threadid
ORDER BY replys DESC, post.dateline DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Now my query tooks about 1 second which is quite too much! What can I do to make the query faster?

Information about the structure of the tables:

**Post**

[image]
[image]

**Thread**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion might sound weird, but it helped me quite often: Use a sub-query.

First just do the counting and reduce the number of fields that are involved in this query to a minimum. Your sub-query should only return the counts and an id that is applicable to get all the other data with (most probably that would be `threadid`).

Then join the result and get the rest of the data.

I wouldn't be surprised if that saves you half a second.